# Inner join failure - returns no data

Tags: sql, inner-join

I am encountering some problems in inner joining a table and a view .
The view is `pageviewforum` with a column `forumn_no varchar2` and a column of `totalcount` which is the count of total pageviews in each forum.

Another table is 
`forum`: `forum_no char(6), forumname varchar2(50)`

I want to output the `totalcount` with the `forum_no` and its forum name but it doesn't work.

```
select forum.forumname, totalcount from pageviewforum 
inner join forum on pageviewforum.forum_no= forum.forum_no;
```

The above query returns the error message of no data. 
I tried to see what comes out of

```
select forum.forumname, totalcount from pageviewforum 
inner join forum on pageviewforum.forum_no > forum.forum_no;
```

and data comes out. I tried to use like but it says no data as well.
What can I do?

Comment: can you add the query in your `view`?

Comment: Did you check the existing values in the two `forum_no` columns? There seem to be no common values...

Comment: can you please try this:                                       Select forum.forumname, pgfrm.totalcount from pageviewforum pgfrm inner join forum frm on pgfrm.forum_no= frm.forum_no;

Comment: Did you notice you're joining on columns of different data types?

Comment: ah so does it work if I put to_char (pageviewforum.forum_no) to  convert it to char and compare it with forum.forum_no ?

Answer (score 5):

Since you are joining a `varchar2` column of indeterminate size with a `char(6)` column, it may be that you are running into differences because of that.  If those columns hold a number, why not use a numeric type (like INTEGER) to hold the values?  It will be more reliable in the long run.  Generally, joining columns work most reliably when they're of the same type.  When they're of different types, you have to worry about whether the two types are compatible enough and whether they compare sensibly.

*Hypothesis*: In particular, a CHAR(6) column is blank-padded to full length; unless the DBMS strips those trailing blanks off, you may never get a CHAR(n) and a VARCHAR(n) to compare equal unless all n characters are in use.  The `>` comparison works because the blanks matter for equality, but the greater than or less than can still come up with an answer.

Observations:

- Column types in a database do matter.
- Consistency is important.

Comment: @MarkBannister: Sorta - it has escaped into other DBMS too.